# How to change the text of the "Swipe Delete" button in TListView - Delphi FireMonkey?

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey

Delphi 10 with Firemonkey: In the ListView, if the `CanSwipeDelete` property is True and if you run Swipe on a ListView item, a **Delete button** will be shown. Is it possible to change the text of this Delete button as shown in the image?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setup it through the list view's [**DeleteButtonText**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.ListView.TListView.DeleteButtonText) property. The reference describes it as:

> Specifies the name of the **Delete** button designed to delete the
>   **TListView** items. This button can be displayed if the **CanSwipeDelete** property is set **True**.

Comment: Damn it! had not noticed this property. Thanks and sorry.

Comment: Was wondering if there's a possibility to put there a Glyph. Using Dynamic appearnce